# Read many JSON documents and union in only one (BigData?)

Tags: javascript, mapreduce, couchdb, bigdata

I need to read many JSON documents and make a merge to generate only one document.

Let me explain: I have a tracking system to capture many events from user navigation in website. I can use attribute ID to map related documents and create merged document.

Example

#### My Input:

```
{ id : "12345", fly : "nyc-bos", time: "10:00am" }
{ id : "12345", fly : "orl-mia", time: "09:00am" }
{ id : "12345", fly : "chi-mem", time: "07:00am" }
{ id : "12345", order: "099300" }
{ id : "12345", order: "677800" }
{ id : "12345", order: "129999" }
{ id : "12345", product: "DVD" }
{ id : "12345", product: "LCD TV" }
```

#### I need a document like this:

```
{
    id: "12345"
          fly :
             "nyc-bos", time: "10:00am"
             "orl-mia", time: "09:00am"
             "chi-mem", time: "07:00am"
          order :
             "099300"
             "677800"
             "129999"
          product :
             "DVD"
             "LCD TV"
}
```

Important:

- I have millions of input documents
- I can't use BigData frameworks (Hadoop, etc)
- My stack is restricted (Windows + C# + CouchDB)

Does someone have an idea I could follow?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You'd just do this in a map/reduce, just a plain `emit(doc.id, doc)` for your map, and then something like this for your reduce:

```
function( keys, values, rereduce ) {
  var doc = {};
  values.forEach( function(d) {
    var dd = doc[d.id] = doc[d.id] || {};

    if(d.fly) {
      dd['fly'] = dd['fly'] || [];
      dd.fly.push({ code: d.fly, time: d.time });
    }
    else if(d.order) {
      dd['order'] = dd['order'] || [];
      dd.order.push(d.order);
    }
    else if(d.product) {
      dd['product'] = dd['product'] || [];
      dd.product.push(d.product);
    }
  });
  return doc;
}
```

Note that I used `code` for the key in your `fly` object, you can't have `"nyc-bos", time: "10:00am"` in JSON, both values need to have keys.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking at is an aggregation of data and it could be achieved with couchdb utilizing two concepts named 'views' and 'lists'. your tech stack should not be a problem since conceptually you could use httpclient to interact with couchdb. I suggest you first read up on couch views, 
https://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Introduction_to_CouchDB_views
http://guide.couchdb.org/draft/views.html
once you are familiar with them you could output a dataset as shown in your first snippet, and that would be where couch 'list' function would play it's role to aggregate the data and output a certain format as in your second snippet. basically a list function stands next to view functions in the pipeline and they will be fed with the output of the view function. you understand this concept in more depth by reading official couchdb docs. for convienience refer the link below.
http://guide.couchdb.org/draft/transforming.html

In a case where one needs to output a dataset of stats ([couch reduce functions](https://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Built-In_Reduce_Functions)) for documents, it may look like this

```
{ "rows":
   [
     {"key":"de", "value":{"sum":2,"count":2,"min":1,"max":1,"sumsqr":2}},
     {"key":"ee", "value":{"sum":2,"count":2,"min":1,"max":1,"sumsqr":2}},
     {"key":"de", "value":{"sum":2,"count":2,"min":1,"max":1,"sumsqr":2}},
     {"key":"ee", "value":{"sum":2,"count":2,"min":1,"max":1,"sumsqr":2}},
     {"key":"de", "value":{"sum":2,"count":2,"min":1,"max":1,"sumsqr":2}}
   ]
}
```

and to aggregate them, so that we can output a dataset with unique keys but aggregated values (min, max etc), we could write a list functions as follows

```
function(head, req) {
  var row;
  var result = [];
  var firstRun = true;
  var found = true;
  start({
    "headers": {
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
     }
  });

while(row = getRow()) {      
      if(firstRun){
          firstRun = false;
          result.push({id: row.key, sum: row.value.sum, count: row.value.count, min: row.value.min, max: row.value.max, sumsqr: row.value.sumsqr});
      }else{
        for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
          if (row.key === result[i].id) {
              result[i].sum += row.value.sum;
              result[i].count += row.value.count;
              result[i].min = ((row.value.min < result[i].min) ? row.value.min : result[i].min);
              result[i].max = ((row.value.max > result[i].max) ? row.value.max : result[i].max);
              result[i].sumsqr = result[i].sum;
              found = true;
            break;
          }else{
            found = false;
          }
        }      
      }
    if(!found){
        result.push({id: row.key, sum: row.value.sum, count: row.value.count, min: row.value.min, max: row.value.max, sumsqr: row.value.sumsqr});
        found = true;
    }
  } return JSON.stringify(result);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a typical case for what is called a [Map/Reduce "collation"](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/1.6.1/couchapp/views/joins.html?highlight=collation#using-view-collation).

Note: Because `id` is misleading (with `_id`, the document identifier), I will call it `user_id`.

First you have to emit the collation key, with no value (never emit `doc` as the value. The lighter your index is, the better. A link to the original doc is automatically done). We will also add the category to the key since you want the results to be sorted as such.

```
function(o) {
    if (o.fly) {
      emit([o.user_id, 'fly']);
    } else if (o.order) {
      emit([o.user_id, 'order']);
    } else if (o.product) {
      emit([o.user_id, 'product']);
    }
}
```

Don't define a reduce function since you want to keep the link to the original document.

Query your view with `include_docs=true` to get the linked documents and choose a user with `startkey` and `endkey`:

```
/mydb/_design/mydesign/_view/myview?include_docs=true&startkey=["12345"]&endkey=["12345",{}]
```

You'll get:

```
[
{"key":["12345", "fly"], "value": null, "doc":{"user_id": "12345", "fly":"nyc-bos", "time":"10:00am"}},
{"key":["12345", "fly"], "value": null, "doc":{"user_id": "12345", "fly": "orl-mia", "time": "09:00am"}},
{"key":["12345", "fly"], "value": null, "doc":{"user_id": "12345", "fly": "chi-mem", "time": "07:00am"}},
{"key":["12345", "order"], "value": null, "doc":{"user_id": "12345", "order": "099300"}},
{"key":["12345", "order"], "value": null, "doc":{"user_id": "12345", "order": "677800"}},
{"key":["12345", "order"], "value": null, "doc":{"user_id": "12345", "order": "129999"}},
{"key":["12345", "product"], "value": null, "doc":{"user_id": "12345", "product": "DVD"}},
{"key":["12345", "product"], "value": null, "doc":{"user_id": "12345", "product": "LCD TV"}}
]
```

All the heavy computing (a.k.a. "restricting", "joining" and "sorting") has been done by Map/Reduce. You can then adjust the formatting with a simple [list function](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/1.6.1/couchapp/ddocs.html#list-functions).